# Matlab: how to update the value of a named range in Excel? (ActiveX)

Tags: excel, matlab, com, range, activex

I am trying to set the value of a named range in Excel from Matlab. Setting the value of a non-named range works fine. For example, assuming I have a named range "TENOR" (consisting of a single cell):

```
  calibFile = '//path/to/calibration-v2.xlsx'

  Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible=1; 
  AllWorkBooks = Excel.Workbooks

  WorkBook = AllWorkBooks.Open(calibFile)
  AllSheets = WorkBook.Sheets
  Sheet = get(AllSheets, 'Item', 1)

  // This Works:
  Sheet.Range('A1').Value = '5y'   

  // This does not work:
  Sheet.Range('TENOR').Value = '5y'
```

Any help on how to set the value of a named range?

Comment: I don't know if it is a transcription mistake, but the last line says Sheet.Name. I think that Sheet.Range('TENOR') should work as well as Sheet.Range('A1')

Comment: @Carlos - oh yes good catch. sadly transcription error, was trying various things. Have corrected question.

Comment: Have you tried Sheet.Range('TENOR').formula = '5y'? .formula worked for me!